# ¿Como puedo recibir un Json que envio desde ajax en php?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Quiero recibir el JSON que mando desde ajax para extraer los datos y almacenarlos en variables. esto ultimo lo quiero hacer en PHP (adjunto abajo todo el código)

Este es el formulario

```
     <form method="post" id="formRegistro">
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required autofocus>

            <label for="correo">Correo</label>
            <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" required>

            <label for="pass">Contraseña</label>
            <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" required>

            <button type="submit" name="enviar" id="btn-Registro">Enviar</button>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Aquí está el Ajax, está en un archivo JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn-Registro').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = "../procesos/proce_registrarAlum.php";
        var data = $("#formRegistro").serialize();

        var jsonDatos = {
            nombre: $("#nombre").val(),
            correo: $("#correo").val(),
            pass: $("#pass").val(),
        };

        var parcejson = JSON.stringify(jsonDatos);

        //console.log(parcejson);
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {'datosAlum': JSON.stringify(jsonDatos)},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                //$('#resp').html(parcejson);
            },

            error: function () {
                $('#resp').html("Error");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Y aquí esta el PHP, lo estoy recibiendo y parceando con JSON_ENCODE, pero no me está tomando.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {

        include "../bbdd/conexion.php";

        $datos = json_encode($_POST['parcejson']);



        $datos = json_encode($_POST['datosAlum']);
        var_dump($datos);

        # Variables a utilizar
        $nombreAlum = json_encode($_POST['nombre']);
        $correoAlum = json_encode($_POST['correo']);
        $claveAlum  = json_encode($_POST['pass']);


?>
```

Sinceramente me he basado en paginas y videos, pero todos lo hacen de manera distinta pero no hacen lo que necesito , prácticamente estoy al intento y error pero ya no se que mas hacer.

No entiendo por que no me llega el resultado, lo envio por JSON , y ajax segun los videos, debería recibirlo, si alguien me puede ayudar a por que no se me muestra en consola y la lógica de lo que estoy haciendo muchas gracias

Comment: Realmente no necesitas usar `JSON.stringify`, puedes mandar los datos así simplemente: `data: {'datosAlum': jsonDatos}`  y luego en el servidor verificar si se envió una clave `datosAlumn`  mediante: `if(isset($_POST['datosAlumn'])) { //aquí trabajar con los datos posteados y devolver una respuesta al cliente que recuperarás en la parte success` Simplemente lo que pasas en el parámetro `data` de Ajax es serializado en la super global del método (`$_POST` en este caso) tomando como clave el valor de la izquierda y como valor el dato de la derecha, que aquí sería un objeto (`jsonDatos`).

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que estás en el buen camino pero te faltaba un poco más de diagnostico para conseguirlo. Al principio del todo de tu PHP estás poniendo: `if(isset($_POST['enviar']))` te aconsejaría antes de esa linea pusieras `var_dump($_POST);` y verías que el problema viene porque no está definida la clave 'datosAlumno', observa que debe coincidir con el nombre que estás poniendo al objeto de tu javascript.

Una vez que resuelvas eso el siguiente problema estaría en el uso de la función `json_encode` la cual toma un string y lo codifica como json. Sin embargo en este caso ya estás recibiendo un json, echale un vistazo a la siguiente función: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Te dejo un ejemplo de como quedaría funcionando el PHP y la respuesta que genera, espero que te ayude.

```
<?php
    echo "Contenido del post:"
    var_dump($_POST);

    if(isset($_POST['datosAlum'])) {
        $datos = json_decode($_POST['datosAlum']);
        echo "Contenido variable datos:"
        var_dump($datos);

        # Variables a utilizar
        $nombreAlum = $datos->nombre;
        $correoAlum = $datos->correo;
        $claveAlum  = $datos->pass;

        echo "Alumno: $nombreAlum \n";
        echo "Correo: $correoAlum \n";
        echo "Clave: $claveAlum \n";
    }
?>
```

Resultado

```
Contenido del post:
array(1) {
  ["datosAlum"]=>
  string(58) "{"nombre":"unNombre","correo":"unCorreo","pass":"unaPass"}"
}
Contenido variable datos:
postobject(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["nombre"]=>
  string(8) "unNombre"
  ["correo"]=>
  string(8) "unCorreo"
  ["pass"]=>
  string(7) "unaPass"
}
Alumno: unNombre 
Correo: unCorreo 
Clave: unaPass
```

Un saludo!

Comment: Muchas Gracias por su respuesta.